# using valgrind at specific point while running program

Tags: valgrind

I want to use `valrgind` at a specific time while my program is running. For example, when I use `-O3` it will take 0.5 hours to reach the desired point. When I use `-g -ggdb` it will take nearly 2.5 hours to reach the desired point.

Now if I use `valgrind` with `-g -ggdb`, the program is extremely slow and I can not predict when it reach the desired point.

What should I do?

Comment: You can use -O3 and -g both. If you want Valgrind starts to check memory problems at your desired point, how do you ensure those problematic memory are not allocated/freed before reaching at this point?